# How to step into code of a library built through terminal not XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker, static-libraries

I am using a open source library, PJSIP, to build a VOIP iphone app. This library is built through several terminal commands and then is used in a sample XCode application provided with te downloaded source. The sample runs properly with no problems.

What i want to know is how can i step into the code of the library from the demo app from within XCode? Since the library is built through the terminal i cannot use the procedure described [here](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/). This one links to libraries built through XCode and imports the xcodeproj file to the other project, which is not my case here.

Any idea how i can do this?
Cheers
AF

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to double klick the file?

If Xcode does not open the file I would recommend to look into the file with vim. Vim can open nearly everything. But it could be that does not help. (You can even open pdf with vim but ... for what...)

Comment: The problem is not with opening the files. XCode is not being able to step into it. The source is not part of my project but its generated libraries are. I have the source of those libraries and i want to debug them from within my app. XCode will not automatically find the source as its not part of the project. There should be a way to link the outside library source for my debugging purposes...and thats what am trying to find. As i said in my post, the library is built through terminal not XCode, this means i don have xcode project for it to link against as suggested in the reference link